# Intermittent sudo failure - SuSE 10

Tags: linux, cron, sudo

We have a longstanding production issue where cron on certain servers periodically report the following error-

```
sudo: uid NNN does not exist in the passwd file!
```

The user does exist, in fact it is the userid of the cron user. There are 7 jobs in that user's crontab, in the format

```
* * * * * sudo /run/this/every_minute
0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * * sudo /run/this/every_5mins
10,40 * * * * sudo /run/this/every_30mins
...
0 11 * * 6 sudo /run/this/once_per_week
```

The every_5mins job sometimes modifies /etc/passwd, but in an atomic fashion. It never touches the userid in question, and when I compare the logs of our /etc/passwd changes and the times which we have received this error, there is no correlation.

I had a look at the sudo code for the version in use (1.6.8p12) and this error comes from the C system call getpwnam returning a null passwd struct pointer.  Other than the obvious reason, it can also fail due to EINTR, EIO, EMFILE, ENFILE or ENOMEM.  sudo doesn't discriminate between the username not being found and these other error conditions.  I think I can assume that cron insulates against EIO and EINTR.  Our servers are monitored and seem to have plenty of memory.  The max FD limit is very high (> 700k).  There aren't any capacity problems that we're aware of, and I think other stuff would be failing if these limits were breached.  This leaves EMFILE, and yet I don't see how this could cause such an error, since it is happening at the very beginning before the command is launched.  I believe EMFILE can only occur if the max FD (1024) is reached in a particular process.

So I'm stumped - any ideas welcome.

Comment: Do you run nscd/sssd? What does the "passwd" line say in nsswitch.conf?

Comment: Work-around, use the UID in sudoers: i.e. `#NNN ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD ALL`.  Sudo 1.8+ should be easier to debug (write a plugin).

Comment: @h0tw1r3: I'm intrigued by the workaround suggestion, I wish I could provoke the problem in dev so that I could test it.

Comment: @Mlfe: ncsd is running, but not sssd, the passwd line is 'files'

Comment: @SueSpence since you're only using `files` in nsswitch.conf, I would definitely disable the nscd service.  The problem will magically disappear.  [nscd sucks](https://www.google.com/search?q=nscd+sucks&safe=active)

Comment: @h0tw1r3 I doubt it will be possible to disable nscd (another team manages this and they'd need a very good reason to do it).  Do you have any background info on why either the sudoers workaround or disabling nscd would fix this weird issue?